# Using VBA to get data from API with bearer token to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, bearer-token

So far I have been using Postman to `GET` data with our bearer token.
I need to get this data into Excel. So far what we've done is download the `.json` using postman, convert the `.json` to `.xml` and open the file with Excel. 
Can I use VBA to pull data from the web that requires bearer token authentication and also can I automatically convert the `.json` data to `.xml`?

I have done some research and found a code

```
Sub GetData()

Dim hReq As Object, Json As Dictionary
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim authKey As String

authKey = {my token key}

Set sht = Sheet1

Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://myurl"
Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
        .Send
    End With

Dim response As String
    response = hReq.ResponseText

    MsgBox response
End Sub
```

But whenever I insert the `authKey` bearer token I have it gives 2 types of errors. Firstly it doesn't like the `{}` brackets `Compile error: invalid character` so okay I removed the curly brackets. But my bearer token key has `.12` in the middle of the code (ex. `125ffhuhf901h201.12afjsfklajflksajkl`) says `Compile error: Expected: end of statement` and highlights the `.12` part.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, removed the curly brackets and used quotation marks instead. 
At the end of the example code it ends with `MsgBox response` but I need it to paste the data into Excel.

Comment: `Sheets("Whatever").Range("A1").Value = response`